# Compare files in 2 directories and keep copying the newly added files from source to desitnation folder

Tags: python-3.x, file, copy, shutil

```
d1_contents = set(os.listdir(r'C:\Users\AUTHORITAH\Desktop\comp_2'))
d2_contents = set(os.listdir(r'E:\comp_1'))
common = list(d1_contents & d2_contents)
common_files = [ f 
            for f in common 
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\AUTHORITAH\Desktop\comp_2', f))
            ]
print ('Common files:', common_files)
match, mismatch, errors = filecmp.cmpfiles(r'C:\Users\AUTHORITAH\Desktop\comp_2', 
                                      # r'E:\comp_1', 
                                       #common_files)
print ('Match:', match)
print ('Mismatch:', mismatch)
print ('Errors:', errors)
```

I am trying to compare the contents of two directories and if I add new data into dir 1 it should get added into dir 2. For ex- If dir 1 has 8 files in it and I add 2 more in it then dir 2 should get updated with those 2 new files as well.

Comment: I tried with shutil.copyfile(src,dest) and other shutil methods but its not working

Comment: you have commented code which makes your code incorrect. Besides what is your exact problem?